# Predictability of countably valued accessible stopping times on complete and cadlag filtrations

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

The following question is motivated by this part of the proof of Lemma 2 on page 107 of the book *Stochastic integration and differential equations* of Philip Protter.

> **Lemma 2.** Let $T$ be a totally inaccessible stopping time. For $\delta > 0$,  let $R(\delta) = \sup_{t \leq v} P(t \leq T \leq t + \delta \vert \mathcal{F}_{t})$. Then $R(\delta) \to 0 $ in probability as $\delta \to 0$.
>
> *Proof of Lemma 2.* Let $a >0$ and $S_{n}(\delta) = \inf \lbrace t \in D_{n}: P(t \leq T \leq t + \delta \vert \mathcal{F}_{t}) > a \rbrace \wedge v.$ First we assume that $S_{n}(\delta)$ is less than $T$. Since $S_{n}$ is countably valued, **it is accessible, and since $T$ is totally inaccessible, $P(S_{n}(\delta) = T)=0$.**  Suppose that $\Gamma \subset \lbrace T< t \rbrace,$ and also $\Gamma \in \mathcal{F}_{t}$. Then
>
> \begin{align}
> E\left[ E\left[ 1_{\lbrace t \leq T \leq t+ \delta \rbrace}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t}\right] 1_{\Gamma}\right] = E \left[ 1_{\lbrace t \leq T \leq t+ \delta \rbrace}  1_{\Gamma} \right] = 0
> \end{align}
>
> $\cdots$

Is every countably accessible stopping time (in a complete and cadlag filtration) a predictable stopping time?

I ask this because what I want to do is to prove that $S_{n}(δ)$ is predictable (I suppose using the fact that it is accessible and countably valued), and therefore I can use the hypothesis that T is totally inaccessible to prove $P(S_{n}(δ)=T)=0$

> **Definition.** A stopping time $T$ is **totally inaccessible** if for every predictable stopping time $S$,
>
> \begin{align}
> P\lbrace w: T(w) = S(w) < \infty \rbrace = 0
> \end{align}

Any reference or hint will be welcome.

Comment: Typing this up would be a good thing for people who use screen readers, and for posterity in case those pictures evaporate, or for those who which to analyse the data in MO questions, or...

Comment: Your question could easily have been asked on [Math.SE]. However, since it's been around for a little while and hasn't yet been migrated (or had someone suggest it should be), I've posted an answer below.

Comment: I would suggest making the title of this post to be more informative and indicate more explicitly the nature of the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, not all accessible stopping times are predictable. However, predictable stopping times are accessible.

A stopping time is accessible whenever its graph is contained in a countable union of graphs of predictable stopping times. Put it another way, a stopping time is accessible whenever it is always equal to one of a countable number of predictable stopping times (up to sets of measure zero).

Comment: I heard about that on filtrations generated by Feller processes $T$ is a predictable stopping time if and only if $T$ and accessible  stopping time.

Comment: @Ivan That sounds like it could be true — Feller processes are known to have nice regularity properties. However, I’m not familiar with that specific result.

Comment: What I want to do is to prove that $S_{n}(\delta)$ is predictable (I suppose using the fact that it is accessible and countably valued), and therefore I can use the hypothesis that $T$ is totally inaccessible to prove $P(S_{n}(\delta) =T ) =0$

Comment: @Ivan But you don’t need the fact that $S_n$ is predictable. (In fact, I strongly suspect that, in general, it may not be.) The fact that $S_n$ is accessible is sufficient to conclude that $P(S_n(\delta) = T) = 0$.

Comment: thanks. You are right. However the question: Is every countably accessible stopping time (in a complete and cadlag filtration) a predictable stopping time? sounds interesting.

Comment: @Ivan I’m fairly certain the answer is no. I don’t have a counter-example on hand, but standard textbooks typically assume the usual conditions (complete right-continuous filtrations) but also still define predictable and accessible stopping times separately. If every accessible stopping time (under the usual conditions) were predictable, then there would be no need for this.

Comment: @Ivan You might be able to construct a counter-example using the results here: https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/compensators-of-stopping-times/ See, in particular, lemma 8.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think one can easily construct a counter-example if the underlying process $X_t$ has jumps at predictable times, or branching points (which, in a sense, are jumps at predictable times in the Ray topology).

Consider the natural (right-continuous) filtration of a process $X_t$ which is identically equal to $0$ with probability $\tfrac{1}{2}$, and equal to $\mathbb{1}_{[1, \infty)}(t)$ also with probability $\tfrac{1}{2}$. Then set $\tau = 1$ in the former case and $\tau = 2$ in the latter one. This way $\tau$ is a stopping time with two values, and hence an accessible time, but clearly not a predictable time.